# Replacement for Microsoft Sync?

Tags: alternatives

So, I recently bought a new (to me) plug-in hybrid: A Ford Fusion. 
Awesome in a lot of ways, but one glaring problem. As I drove one day, I noticed the dreaded Microsoft logo. Besides the obvious joke of "why have a company known for making things crash implementing car parts?" I have noticed not only is Microsoft Sync buggy, but also half the features require payments for a proprietary service (a proprietary service, I might add, which has been discontinued, meaning half the functionality of my car's computer system is gone.) Now me, being a linux fan, obviously thought, "Well hey, I know what I would have preferred anyway..."

The problem is, I have been hunting for any kind of Linux distro built to be a replacement car assistant OS, and have found none. Heck, I have found pretty much nothing about replacing a half-nerfed Microsoft Sync with *anything*.

Are there any linux alternatives to M$'s abandoned car OS?

[Note: I'd be shocked if there isn't one, since Microsoft Sync is always-focused app over Mircosoft Windows Embedded Automotive edition mixed with the unix-like QNX... seems like it'd be a straightforward replacement.]

Comment: I have also been searching but here's a little further insight I found on the OS used in the car: https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=8736056

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, just found out about https://www.automotivelinux.org/.

So far best lead I know of. Still looking into more details.